# How to convert DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES to VARCHAR2?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

When using the DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES that gives a result of DBMS_OUTPUT.CHARARR, how to can you convert that to varchar2 ? I want to use the DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES to get all of my DBMS_PUTLINE statements and return them as string to a calling program.

Database:Oracle 12c

PLSQL Version:Version 11.0.6.1776

```
declare
  -- Non-scalar parameters require additional processing 

  v_Data      DBMS_OUTPUT.CHARARR;
  v_NumLines  NUMBER;
begin
  -- Call the procedure


  -- Procedure that will generate DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINEs 
  executeProcFoo( );

  v_NumLines := 1000;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES(v_Data, v_NumLines);

  FOR v_Counter IN 1..v_NumLines LOOP
       --output putlines from get_lines
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_Data(v_Counter));
  END LOOP; 
end;
```

Comment: `dbms_output.chararr` is already an array of `varchar2`. What do you mean by converting it to `varchar2`? Do you want it in one long string? Or do you need to publish it as some other collection type that is more compatible with your calling framework?

Comment: Yes as one long string. I would like to return the result as one string to a calling java application.

Comment: Why? Surely Java has arrays? But in any case, just loop through the array appending it to a suitable text variable. I'm still not seeing the technical issue.

Comment: Ya I wasn't sure how I would handle that resultset in JAVA. I should of asked the root of the question. How to handle a dbms_output.charaar called from java. Attempting to fetch the result to print to console from spring integration. I will post that separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
   -- Non-scalar parameters require additional processing

   v_Data       DBMS_OUTPUT.CHARARR;
   v_NumLines   NUMBER;

   TYPE v IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (1000)
                INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   v_var        v;
BEGIN
   -- Call the procedure


   -- Procedure that will generate DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINEs
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('vvvv');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('xxxxx');

   v_NumLines := 1000;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES (v_Data, v_NumLines);

   FOR v_Counter IN v_data.FIRST .. v_data.LAST
   LOOP
      --output putlines from get_lines
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_Data (v_Counter));
      v_var (v_counter) := v_data (v_counter);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

You can pass then v_var to any procedure or function.

Comment: I would like to return a single string to java calling this stored procedure. In that case would I build the varchar2 by looping through the table of v to build the returning final string?

Comment: Yes you can do this.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments it seems like you are just looking for a convenient way to fetch the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer into your Java application. While there are ways to publish SQL types as Java-compatible arrays (I'm not a Java developer so I'll leave that to others - but note that `dbms_output.get_lines` is overloaded and can return a `dbmsoutput_linesarray` which might be easier to work with than a `dbms_output.chararray`), it occurred to me that a ref cursor might do the trick.

If so, you can create a function that returns the output buffer as a collection:

```
create or replace function get_dbms_output
    return dbmsoutput_linesarray
as
    l_output dbmsoutput_linesarray;
    l_linecount number;
begin
    dbms_output.get_lines(l_output, l_linecount);

    if l_output.count > l_linecount then
        -- Remove the final empty line above l_linecount
        l_output.trim;
    end if;

    return l_output;
end get_dbms_output;
```

Now you can issue a normal SQL query as

```
select column_value from table(get_dbms_output)
```

which should give you a standard ref cursor.

Demo:

```
SQL> set serveroutput off
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_output.enable;
  3      dbms_output.put_line('This is a line');
  4      dbms_output.put_line('This is another line');
  5      dbms_output.put_line('This is the last line.');
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select column_value from table(get_dbms_output);

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------
This is a line
This is another line
This is the last line.

3 rows selected.
```

(The `set serveroutput off` is just to stop SQL*Plus from doing its own `dbms_output.get_lines` at the end of the call and leaving my function with nothing to do. The `dbms_output.enable` is because `set serveroutput off` disables dbms_output. These are just for demo purposes in SQL*Plus and you won't need either of them in Java.)

Comment: What would the variable type be for column_value?

Comment: Ah, good point - it's a `varchar2(32767)`, which now I think about it might give you some issues with lines longer than 4000 bytes (unless you're on Oracle 12c and you've [enabled extended datatypes](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1)).

Comment: I just tested with a 4001-character line and it failed with `ORA-24920: column size too large for client`, although I suspect that if the client hadn't rejected the value it still would have failed with something else. Maybe I could make it a pipelined function and have it check each line and split it if necessary, so it won't fail but it might break some formatting and split some words in two unless I add a bunch more logic.

Comment: Ya I was able to covert it to varchar but I could see it easily exceeding the varchar length for some longer outputs I could have. I'm trying to see if I can send back the linesarray type to the spring integration call and ready it as the array type.

Comment: How would you return the ref cursor instead of the dbmsoutput_linesarray? I am using oracle 12c.

Comment: I don't know Java but I was assuming it's easy to fetch results from a cursor.